# How to define logical operator with parenthesis in ANTLR grammar

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar

I am defining a grammar in ANTLR that will express an expression which includes logical operator and parenthesis together. 

Here is the grammar

```
grammar simpleGrammar; 

/* This will be the entry point of the parser. */ 

parse 
    :   
        expression EOF 
    ; 
expression 
    :   
        expression binOp expression | ID | unOp (expression) | '(' expression ')' 
    ; 
binOp 
    : 
        ('AND' | 'OR')  
    ; 
unOp 
    : 
        'NOT' 
    ; 
ID      :   
        ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+  
    ;
```

The defined grammar can able to express parse tree without parenthesis but when I input an example with parenthesis for example, `(Apple OR Bananana)AND Orange`
It is showing `MismatchedTokenException` 

So, It will be really appreciated if someone explains how to define the grammar in order to express the parenthesis.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to tell ANTLR what to do with whitespace. For example:

```
WS : [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

Add this and you grammar will work.

As a side note, your grammar has the same precedence for the `AND` and `OR` operators. And these operators have higher precedence than `NOT`. As this goes against conventional rules, I'd advise you to write your `expression` rule like this instead:

```
expression 
    :   '(' expression ')'            # parenExp
    |   'NOT' expression              # notExpr
    |   expression 'AND' expression   # andExpr
    |   expression 'OR' expression    # orExpr
    |   ID                            # atomExpr
    ;
```

Comment: Its shows an exception since it is mutually left recursive `expression 'AND' expression` and `expression 'OR' expression`

Comment: Nope, it's a directly left-recursive expression. ANTLR4 is capable of handling these, ANTLR3 is not. Your original question contains a direct left-recursion too so I supposed you're on v4.